# how to assign json array of values to an array in angular

Tags: angular

i have a json array of values ,

```
array1 = [{"type":"cc"},{"type":"vv"},{"type":3},{"type":4},{"type":5}];
```

i have another array array 2, i need to fill the second array by checking the condition ,that the value with the type =vv ,want to be the first element in the second array.
i use the format,

```
array1.forEach((pp)=>{
   if(pp.type == 'cc'){
     array2[1] = pp;
   }
   else if(pp.type == 'vv' ){
      array2[0] = pp;
   }
   else if(pp.type == '4' ){
      array2[3] = pp;
   }
   else if(pp.type == '3' ){
      array2[2] = pp;
   }
 else if(pp.type == '5' ){
      array2[4] = pp;
   }
})
```

but after execution i got empty array as the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very concise solution using `Array.sort()`, and this doesn't constrain having 2 elements only of course:

```
array1.sort((a,b) => a.type === 'vv'? -1: 1);
```

Comment: i need to check 5 condition and make order related to the condition.is it possible with array.sort function ?

Comment: Well, if you have exactly 5 elements (fixed size) that you want to sort in a predetermined matter, I don't get why would that even bother you. 
Your array `array2` comes back empty, maybe you initialized it wrongly, you can do `array2 = new Array(5)` ?